# How to embed YouTube videos without cookies?

Tags: cookies, youtube

In the past we could embed YouTube videos without cookies by simply pointing to a different URL, so for example https://youtube-nocookie.com/embed/sRrqF8eXs38 to get the version without cookies.

This does not work any longer. The URL returns a *404*, where the cookie version still exists.

I could not find any reference on how to do it now.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the www version, that works perfectly fine: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/sRrqF8eXs38

That is the version their automatic code generator outputs as well, when you chose the extended privacy option.

Looks like they removed the non-www version for some reason. (Although doing that without adding an automatic redirect would be kind of a weird move. Perhaps it is just a temporary problem or error.)

Comment: Yes, works perfectly with the `www` prefix. Changing it without giving notice would be a very strange move, so I hope it is just temporary.

Comment: I see they are still adding NID preferences setting cookie

Comment: @jrosell yes, it is not _absolutely_ cookie-less - but it avoids all the standard tracking cookies they would set otherwise.

Comment: Is it strange that I started watching the video? :)

Comment: When I inspect the cookie section in Chrome Dev Tools > Application, there are lots of cookies for https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/sRrqF8eXs38 … Can anyone verify? Is it broken?

Comment: @JimMorrison that article is from 2009 already ... Testing the above URL, the only cookie I'm getting, even after pressing play, is `CONSENT=PENDING+[three digits here]`. They store some more data in Local- and SessionStorage though.

Comment: at the time of this comment there is an automatic redirect to www, so it works without www as well.