# iframe src attribute is changing into data-src in my React application

Tags: reactjs, iframe, src

In a React component I have an iframe:

```
<iframe
  css={styles.videoIframe}
  width="853"
  height="480"
  src={embedlink}
  frameBorder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowFullScreen
  title={title}
/>
```

When I am inspecting the DOM I see `src` has been changed to `data-src`?

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/youtube-id-here" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" title="The title"></iframe>
```

I don't see the embedded YouTube video rendered? It might because of changing the attribute into `data-src`?

Comment: Maybe you are unaware of some other part of the system you are working on that implements this as some sort of user-consent-must-be-given-before-youtube-stuff-is-shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the no-cookies embed for this. It works fine after changing my embed variable to:

```
const embedLink = `https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/${youtubeId}`;
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555450/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-without-cookies/42555610) answer.